# How do I force a refresh in google app maker

Tags: google-app-maker

I have a simple panel that includes a form and a table.  All data but one column in the table are entered.  The values in the non-entry column are calculated.  How do I get the table to refresh itself when after I run a server side script to calculate a new value to show updated table?

Answer (score 5):

If you run your server script from client, then you'll need to use use callback:

```javascript
google.script.run
  .withSuccessHandler(function() {
    app.datasources.MyDatasource.load();
  })
  .withFailureHandler(function() {
    // TODO: handle error
  })
  .myServerScript();
```

In case your server script is executed by some schedule (trigger) or by other users then you'll need to reload table's datasource from time to time:

```javascript
// Page  onAttach event handler
var interval = setInterval(function() {
    app.datasources.MyDatasource.load();
  }, 3000);

// Page onDetach event handler
clearInterval(interval);
```

Comment: Worked like a charm.  Thank you.

Comment: You are welcome! You can accept this answer to help other App Maker users like you.